# ASP.NET Core 1.0 for enterprise applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am figuring out architectural components for my new web project. I am thinking to go with ASP.NET Core 1.0, EF7 stack. Some people suggest that ASP.NET Core 1.0 is in it's initial stage and it's not recommended to use it in enterprise web applications presently. Same opinions I heard in case of EF7 as well.

Mainly I want to know the disadvantages. Experts please explain the pros and cons of using ASP.NET Core 1.0 at present.

Comment: What are your reasons for choosing ASP.Net Core and EF7?

Comment: are you doing that for your education purpose ?

Comment: it seems It consists of modular components with minimal overhead, so you retain flexibility while constructing your solutions, from https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html

Comment: not an expert, but I started a .NET Core project from scratch and the tooling is unfinished at best. Even the syntax highlighting is off/slow. My experience in VSCode is better than in VS2015.

Comment: There are other points also in this article which tells like Asp.Net Core will be future of Microsoft web platform

Comment: I am not going to use it for education purpose. It's for an Enterprise web system, my team is going to develop from scratch.

Comment: The system itself is pretty functional, however if you are going to use .NET Core don`t expect all the libraries to work since they need to be compatible with .NET Core as well. Just an example: HtmlAgilityPack does not work, MongoDB drivers do not work, and many other nuget packages do not work. Not to say they will never will, but it will take time.

Comment: For commercial, no. We have a project with ASP.NET Core 1 "RC1" for internal website has some problem but still work.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere they are true and somewhere they are wrong. ASP.NET Core is targeted by 2 frameworks **.NET Core** and **.NET Framework**. Both options are available in Visual Studio. You have to carefully choose, what is right for your project. Here are some differences\suggestions with ASP.NET Core and EF Core (EF 7 previously):

- All .NET Framework Libraries (BCL or FCL) are not yet available for CoreFx (.NET Core library) but soon they will be available as the .NET team announced.
- If your project uses .NET Framework libraries such as *MailMessage* and others, the use ASP.NET Core targeted with .NET Framework not .NET Core then you will be able to get all the features of .NET Framework in your ASP.NET Core application.
- ASP.NET Core uses modern web work-flow for reducing page load times and for other attributes some of them are not available with the previous versions of ASP.NET.
- EF Core 1.0 is new and cloud-optimized, it does not include (at least for now) featues which are available in EF 6.x such as *Stored Procedures Mapping*, *Built-In feature for Seeding data* and others.

If you want commercial projects that strongly rely on EF 6.x features which are not available now in EF Core, you can use **ASP.NET Core 1.0 with .NET Framework** with **EF 6.x**. I've a [websites](http://kjanshair.azurewebsites.net) also created with ASP.NET Core with .NET Framework.

[Here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/index.html) are some documentations for using ASP.NET Core 1.0 with EF 6.x and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. anyone have any other views in this? Please share, if any.